# paragraph containing image gets broken when it overflows to following page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to generate a PDF with iTextSharp for a library catalog. The format i am after is roughly like this : 
a line for the title, followed by a line for the book information such as year, Isbn,pages .... followed by the abstract of the book wrapping around its cover image, something like what's done [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images)

My problem is with the text and the image. I am using a paragraph as the parent container for another paragraph hosting the abstract and an image object.

```
Paragraph container = new Paragraph();
//cover is an object of type iTxtSharp.text.Image
cover.ScaleToFit(100f, 150f);
cover.IndentationLeft = 9f;
cover.SpacingAfter = 9f;
cover.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.TEXTWRAP | iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
Paragraph blurb = new Paragraph(@pub.Abstract,propertyFont);
blurb.Alignment=Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
container.Add(cover);
container.Add(blurb);
```

using the above i get the desired behavior, however when my paragraph overflows to the following page, or when there is no abstract, the images start drifting to the center.
If i set blurb.KeepTogether to true, the image disappears.
I also tried to use a table with two columns, one for the abstract and another for the page and again the image disappeared.

How can i achieve this desired layout?

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Note that I wrote this TEXTWRAP functionality in the year 2000, but I haven't been using it since we introduced irregular column support for `ColumnText` which may very well be 10 years ago.

Comment: Hello, I am using version 5.4.4. great work btw

Comment: It sounds like a bug, and if so, it's a bug that has been present in iText for over 10 years. It probably went unnoticed, because everybody uses irregular columns to achieve what you want. See http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=67 and http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter03/movie_columns4.pdf for an example.

Comment: If I have time in the weekend, I'll try making an example that reproduces the problem, and see if I can find a fix. Note that I usually don't have much spare time, so please don't be disappointed if I don't have a solution by Monday.